# persistent header in phoneGap ios

Tags: ios, cordova, header

I am new to phonegap. I am trying to implement a simple sliding menu in all pages. How do I get this menu to come on all pages without re-writing the same code on all pages?

Do let me know.

Comment: Which framework you are using for UI?

Comment: m not using any framework as such, just normal html.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout JQuery Mobile (http://jquerymobile.com) or JQTouch (http://jqtjs.com) for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery Mobile Framework,then you can write the below code in the body tag of your html page:-

```
<div data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" id="gs-header">
        <a href="#nav-panel" class="bar-icon" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">&#xe2af;</a>
        <h1 id="groupName"></h1>
</div>
<div data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-display="push" data-theme="b" id="nav-panel"></div>
```